# how that code of Javascript work with slice?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, slice, cryptojs, pycrypto

i try to know how this script is working but i cant understand any one could help me with that?  i need to run it in python or php (its just extract correct base64 format)

i tried that w python

```
 

v = "ielyJfjdCI6InRqTFRWdkEVaTVdSbkcRXUFRpWmRhUaWZoVGR3eFJNbnhZYUJuSW00Q2gxelZycThtNHZscEZYR3hMU3NERW9zVjIiLCJpdiI6IjhmMTcyYWMxNDNhZjZhMTVkYWZhYmEzMDQ4MWUzOWQzIiwicyI6IjA0M2FkZWM1NDk5MjlhMjcifQ"
r =  [10, 30, 20, 1, 1, 0]
for x in r:
   print(v[:x])
```

```js
          var _0x323ex24 = "ielyJfjdCI6InRqTFRWdkEVaTVdSbkcRXUFRpWmRhUaWZoVGR3eFJNbnhZYUJuSW00Q2gxelZycThtNHZscEZYR3hMU3NERW9zVjIiLCJpdiI6IjhmMTcyYWMxNDNhZjZhMTVkYWZhYmEzMDQ4MWUzOWQzIiwicyI6IjA0M2FkZWM1NDk5MjlhMjcifQ==";
            var _0x323ex10 = [40, 30, 20, 5, 2, 0];
            for (var _0x323ex25 = 0; _0x323ex25 < _0x323ex10.length; _0x323ex25++) {
                _0x323ex24 = _0x323ex24.slice(0, _0x323ex10[_0x323ex25]) + _0x323ex24.slice(_0x323ex10[_0x323ex25] + 1)
            };           
            console.log(_0x323ex24)
```

Comment: Please look at your post after hitting "post", because what you've got right now is a markup mess. Hit edit, and fix all this "code that isn't styled as code", "code with tons of  leading whitespace", etc. We have a special [markup article](/editing-help) just for this, which is linked and immediately accessible on the page where you write your post, for a good reason. [format your post properly](/help/how-to-ask) as a courtesy to the real human beings you're asking for help.

Comment: The snippet editor even has a Tidy button to help do it automatically.

Comment: Also, what’s up with the variable names?

Comment: that cuz js code was obfuscator

Comment: i need to know what the slice job on this code so i can tranfaster it to python

Comment: `_0x323ex24` is being modified in the for loop in the JS version. You are not doing that in the Python version.

Comment: I suggest doing a search and replace on the variable names. Even using `a`, `b`, `c`, etc would be easier to read that the current names.

Comment: can u give me example of the top code?

Comment: I think he means you just need to do `v = v[:x]+v[x+1:]` inside your for loop, and `print(v)` outside of it.

Comment: Also worth noting is that your two strings are slightly different. The js one has `==` at the end while the python one does not. Typically the `==` is used to pad a base 64 string correctly.

Comment: oh shit i fixed it with v i did not accept i was missing that , thx khauri

Comment: i dont know how to answer the soultion in stackoverflow :( but the problem was fixed

Comment: Just make an answer yourself. Use the "Your Answer" field below and when done, click the "Post Your Answer" button. Quite straight-forward, isn't it?